# Output to another terminal window C++

Tags: c++

[Linux]

I'm writing a CLI based program in C++. I'm looking to use the main terminal window for all my main I/O for the program however I would like to output some info to a separate terminal window. Is there a way to do this?

example:

```
void debug(std::string output)
{
    //open new terminal
    ...

    std::cout << output << std::endl;
}

//output to debug window
debug("reach point");
```

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. You can write a (linux/udp/tcp) socket client and a server. Sounds like too much work, though. Another way is to write to a shared file (memory?) and monitor changes. Sounds like too much work as well. What is the point of doing that? Why two terminals?

Comment: I just want to monitor the program while its running and not clutter the main window with lots of debug information. I'm aware I could log it to a file using fstream but id rather do it with a separate terminal.

Comment: log it to file, add tags and monitor the file with combination of grep and tail.

Comment: perfect thank you :D still new to all this, got a lot to learn